# Limit of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 \choose n}{2n^2 \choose n} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 \choose n}{2n^2 \choose n} $$ How to solve this? I tried expanding to its factorial form but got nowhere.

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: I don't know what Stirling formula is. Please could you explain or perhaps attach a link. Thanks.

Comment: the searched Limit is zero

Comment: denote by $$a_n=\frac{\binom{n^2}{n}}{\binom{2n^2}{n}}$$ and compute $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Comment: @user1712 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: sorry i have forgotten to write the full comment

Answer (score 1):

If we expand using $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$ (where $n^{\underline{k}}$ denotes [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)), we get

$$\frac{\binom{n^2}{n}}{\binom{2n^2}{n}} = \frac{\big( n^2 \big)^{\underline{n}}}{\big( 2n^2 \big)^{\underline{n}}} \leqslant \frac{\big( n^2 \big)^n}{\big( 2n^2-n \big)^n}$$

and the right side clearly goes to zero.